# Go Revel framework port 9000 already in use

Tags: nginx, go, localhost, port, revel

I'm following along with [the Go Revel framework nicely](http://robfig.github.io/revel/tutorial/createapp.html) until I go to run the test app:

`$ revel run myapp`

which gives me the all the correct output but also gives the following **error**:

```
ERROR 2013/09/30 19:51:41 harness.go:167: Failed to start reverse proxy: listen tcp 
<nil>:9000: address already in use
```

When I run this:

`$ sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:9000 | grep LISTEN`

I get this:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
php-fpm 11007 root   11u  IPv4 0xffffff801441dde0      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 11008 _www    0u  IPv4 0xffffff801441dde0      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 11009 _www    0u  IPv4 0xffffff801441dde0      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 11010 _www    0u  IPv4 0xffffff801441dde0      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
```

I have a PHP-NGINX app running on port 80 and **don't want to lose that** but have no idea whether this means this PHP app is blocking my Go app from running.

Can anyone chime in?

I'm running on MacOS X 10.7.5.

Comment: WHy not just change the port of your revel app with either app.conf or  `revel run myapp dev 8888`?

Comment: Cha-Ching that works! feel free to post that as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the port of a revel application with either:

1. Editing the `config/app.conf` file and setting

   ```
   http.port = 8888
   ```
2. Running your revel application with a parameter specifying the port. You'll also need to specify either `dev` or `prod` to state your environment:

   ```
   revel run myapp dev 8888
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to check out process is already running on this port by using lsof:

```
lsof -i :9000
```

Sometime, you see lsof is not installed on your system then first install lsof:

```
sudo apt-get install lsof
```

If same application running on this port, you should kill process and start again:

```
kill -9 PORT
```

In case some other process is running on this port then you should change default port as suggested by @Vanessa

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to run

```
ps -A | grep revel
```

It is possible that your revel app is still running. If it is, you can kill it with

```
kill PID
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running Nginx / PHP FPM which will use port 9000 for the FPM process communication.

You can change this in your PHP-FPM configuration to either a different port or to use a local socket (preferable) if both Nginx and the php install are on the same machine) but be sure to update your Nginx site definitions to reflect this change as well.

For PHP search your php-fpm.conf for the listen directive:

```
; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses on a
;                            specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

And in Nginx update the fastcgi_pass directive:

```
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Restart both Nginx and PHP-FPM and you should be able to bind to port 9000 again.